# KnexJS raw query in migration

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have a problem with the following migration in KnexJS, working with PostgreSQL:

```
exports.up = (knex) => {
    knex.raw('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"');

    return knex.schema.createTable('car_brands', (table) => {
        table.uuid('brandId').unique().notNullable().primary().defaultTo(knex.raw('uuid_generate_v4()'));
        table.string('name').notNullable().unique();
        table.timestamp('created_at').notNullable().defaultTo(knex.raw('now()'));
        table.timestamp('updated_at').notNullable().defaultTo(knex.raw('now()'));
    });
};

exports.down = (knex) => {
    knex.raw('drop extension if exists "uuid-ossp"');
    return knex.schema.dropTable('car_brands');
};
```

I am using the `UUID` type for my default values, by using the
`defaultTo(knex.raw('uuid_generate_v4()'))`.

However, when running the above migration, by:

```
knex migrate:latest --env development --knexfile knexfile.js --debug true
```

I get an error that:

```
function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist
```

Do you know why the `knex.raw()` query method is not working?

Comment: Probably, the problem is `knex.raw("CREATE EXTENSION ...")` and `knex.schema.createTable()` running asynchronously and the first query is not executed before the second starts. Try to add `await` before the first query or place second query in `then()`

Comment: Hi @Saka7! It helped with placing the `knex.raw()` as a promise and put the second query in `then()` block. Thank you for your help :)  Problem solved!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is you are running

```
knex.raw('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"');
```

and

```
knex.schema.createTable('car_brands');
```

asynchronously, so the first query is not executed before the second one.

Rewrite it using `async/await`:

```
exports.up = async (knex) => {
    await knex.raw('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"');

    return knex.schema.createTable('car_brands', (table) => {
        table.uuid('brandId').unique().notNullable().primary().defaultTo(knex.raw('uuid_generate_v4()'));
        table.string('name').notNullable().unique();
        table.timestamp('created_at').notNullable().defaultTo(knex.raw('now()'));
        table.timestamp('updated_at').notNullable().defaultTo(knex.raw('now()'));
    });
};
```

or using `Promises`:

```
exports.up = (knex) => {
    knex.raw('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"')
        .then(() => {
            return knex.schema.createTable('car_brands', (table) => {
                table.uuid('brandId').unique().notNullable().primary().defaultTo(knex.raw('uuid_generate_v4()'));
                table.string('name').notNullable().unique();
                table.timestamp('created_at').notNullable().defaultTo(knex.raw('now()'));
                table.timestamp('updated_at').notNullable().defaultTo(knex.raw('now()'));
            });
        })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I took to resolve this issue in my app with PostgreSQL, Objection and KNEX.

1. Go to your database to verify your extension is available.

   ```
   postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_extension;
   ```
2. Verify "uuid-ossp" is installed in the database_name you need.

   ```
   database_name=# CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp"
   ```
3. Back to your app, go to the KNEX migration file where you are altering your table.

   ```
   t.uuid('user_id').defaultTo(knex.raw('uuid_generate_v4()'));
   ```
4. Use the KNEX command to get the Batch running:

   ```
   knex migrate:latest
   ```
5. Insert a new raw in your table and verify your UUID has been auto-generated.

I hope these steps can be helpful.